# How to Keep Windows Command Prompt Window Open After Running a PHP Script from Task Scheduler?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

I run various PHP scripts from the Windows 10 Task Scheduler, and the command prompt window closes after running them.  Is there a way to pass an argument from the task scheduler interface to cmd.exe so the Command Prompt window doesn't close after running a specific PHP script?  If so ... How?

Comment: Did you check the options of `cmd.exe /?`.  The `/K` option _might_ be what you want.

Comment: Thx. Yes. I tried prepending (fails to execute) and appending /k (no effect) to the task scheduler's arguments and programs / scripts fields. Either option fails or has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Your comment led me to this useful bit of php code: `` exec(`cmd /K`); ``